# Свойства класса HttpWebRequest конвейерная передача и передача сегментами

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Что имеется в виду под конвейерной передачей и передачей сегментами, задаваемыми свойствами Pipelined и SendChunked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pipelined** - включена по умолчанию. Разрешает использовать [HTTP pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) - клиент может послать сразу "пачкой" множество запросов к серверу, не дожидаясь на них ответа, после чего точно так же "пачкой" получить на них ответы в абсолютно том-же порядке.

**Chunked** - по умолчанию выключена. Позволяет клиенту использовать [Chunked-кодирование](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). Обычно HTTP-запросы требуют указания в заголовке точного размера всего тела запроса. Однако на момент начала отправки запроса, вы  можете не знать сколько точно данных вы планируете передать(например, если вы формируете тело запроса динамически, прямо в момент отправки). Chunked-кодирование позволяет не указывать сразу длину всего тела запроса, а передавать тело маленькими кусочками(chunk-ами), у которых размер указан перед их началом. К сожалению, это кодирование поддерживается далеко не всеми HTTP-серверами.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё понятно.